# What's the meaning of v19 behind drawables?

Tags: android, drawable

What's the meaning of v19 behind drawable? for example: drawable-hdpi-v19?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Table 2 in doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) describes all possible options for res folders.

v19 means at least API19 (4.4)

Answer (score 0):

It describes the API Level. In this case API 19+ (Android 4.4)

That is probably because of the updated [Design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/new.html). For example touch:

> Touch feedback
>
> Before Android KitKat, Android's default touch feedback color was a
>   vibrant blue. Every touch resulted in a jolt of high-contrast color,
>   in a shade that might not have mixed well with your brand's color(s).
>
> In Android KitKat and beyond, touch feedback is subtle: when something
>   is touched, by default its background color slightly darkens or
>   lightens. This provides two benefits: (1) sprinkles of encouragement
>   are more pleasant than jolts, and (2) incorporating your branding is
>   much easier because the default touch feedback works with whatever hue
>   you choose. Check the updated Touch Feedback page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The API level of the resource (v19 -> 19+ kitkat 4.4).

You could use it for drawable, values, xml etc. for every resource.

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1
>   (devices with Android 1.0 or higher) and v4 for API level 4 (devices
>   with Android 1.6 or higher). See the Android API levels document for
>   more information about these values.